# parted and fdisk not showing new size after expanding a RAID 1 volume (Proxmox/Debian)

Tags: debian, raid1, proxmox, megaraid, expansion

Background:
I need to extend a RAID 1 volume from a live Proxmox/Debian server that has a LSI SAS 2108 MegaRAID card, from 1TB to 2TB, I did this on a test environment albeit it was with a different Raid card, and my procedure was replacing each drive one at a time while waiting for the volume to rebuild each time, once that was finished I expanded the RAID 1 volume and after it reconfigured Proxmox recognized the bigger drive. I then created a new partition with the free space and added it to the proxmox **/dev/pve/data** lvgroup group and expanded that volume. Everything went great didn't even have to unmount dev/pve/data and consequently reboot the VMs.

I started doing this on the live server, already replaced each disk seperatly and than expanded the logical RAID 1 drive. Currently the server has 1 RAID 1 Volume showing up as 2TB on the MegaRAID Storage Manager.

However when I move over to the Debian/Proxmox OS to create the new partition with the free space I noticed the extra space is not appearing, neither in **fdisk** or **parted**. The weird thing though is that it does appear in **smartctl**. Here is the output for the commands:

fdisk

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 999.0 GB, 998999326720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121454 cylinders, total 1951170560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1951170559   975585279+  ee  GPT
```

parted

```
# (parted) print free /dev/sda
Model: SMC SMC2108 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               Grub-Boot-Partition   bios_grub
 2      2097kB  136MB   134MB   fat32        EFI-System-Partition  boot, esp
 3      136MB   999GB   999GB                PVE-LVM2-Partition    lvm
        999GB   999GB   1032kB  Free Space
```

smartctl

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-48-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Vendor:               SMC
Product:              SMC2108
Revision:             2.13
User Capacity:        1,998,998,994,944 bytes [1.99 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x600304801b0f130120406495107d7c01
Serial number:        00017c7d109564402001130f1b800403
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Sat Nov  3 13:02:42 2018 WET
Device does not support SMART
```

Notice how it detects it as 2TB. Does anyone why parted and fdisk don't recognize the extra space? Is it possible that I need to reboot the server for it to be detected? I'm trying to avoid rebooting it but if it's necessary I can still do it. I'll be honest i'm not sure if I did reboot the server on the test environment, it's possible I did although I don't think that i did.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer? The change in RAID array size won't be visible to the OS until you restart it.

Comment: I have not, not yet, I was hoping that there was a way to do this without rebooting the server as I think I didn't have to reboot it on my test enviroment, but maybe I'm mistaken, I'm not really sure right now.